# Excel VBA - Combining multiple worksheet selection changes

Tags: excel, vba

I am a novice in vba trying to get my head around it for a spreadsheet I'm working on.

I have two codes that work individually but am having great difficulty combining them. Any idea on the best way to combine them?

First code is to open a dialog box when I click on column 18.

Second code is to select multiple selections from a drop down validation list. Taken from this link: https://trumpexcel.com/select-multiple-items-drop-down-list-excel/

I'm also interested in applying the second code to multiple columns, would this be possible in some way?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 17 Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle 3").Visible = True
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle 2").Visible = True
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle 2").TextFrame.Characters.Text = Range("A" & (ActiveCell.Row)) & " - " & Range("B" & (ActiveCell.Row))
        With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle 3")
            .Left = Target.Offset(, 1).Left
            .Top = Target.Offset(0).Top
        End With
        With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle 2")
            .Left = Target.Offset(0, 2).Left
            .Top = Target.Offset(0, 0).Top
        End With
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle 3").Visible = False
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle 2").Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String
Application.EnableEvents = True
On Error GoTo Exitsub
If Target.Column = 12 Then
  If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
    GoTo Exitsub
  Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Newvalue = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    Oldvalue = Target.Value
      If Oldvalue = "" Then
        Target.Value = Newvalue
      Else
        If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
            Target.Value = Oldvalue & ";" & Newvalue
      Else:
        Target.Value = Oldvalue
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Are these two codes identical? Take this `Event` and turn it into a`Sub Procedure`. Then, your `Event` will just call your `Sub Procedure` and you can apply it to whatever sheets you want

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 

Sorry, I pasted the wrong code - fixed it now!